# Using two "it"s in a sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

So I am pretty bad at English which I put down to apathy/Dyslexia when I was younger as you are about to find out.

I was writing a sentence on Skype just now to my friend and it did not seem right, it went as follows.

"Yeah the more I see of it it seams over hyped"

Now having 2 "it"s in a sentence can not be right, where have I gone wrong and what would be the correct way to write it?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Judging by the type of mistakes made in the writing here, I think the asker is actually a native speaker, just not verbally adept.

Comment: @user1704427 As others have said, there’s some parallelism missing in what you wrote on Skype. However, your basic premise, that “having two ‘it’s in a sentence cannot be right”, does not hold up. There’s nothing wrong with having two ‘it’s in a row if the construction calls for it. “This is such a sad movie. Every time I watch it, it makes me cry”, for example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree the question is a better fit for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com); I just don’t think it does so because the asker is non-native, but because the question is quite basic.

Comment: @Janus: I just cut&pasted the entirety of the second sentence from a little text file I keep on my desktop because I got tired of typing similar things. Yes, obviously OP is a native speaker - but I remain of the opinion that ELU should primarily be for competent speakers to *discuss* English usage. ELL should be the first port of call for people who want to *learn* proper use of the language.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm intrigued by your use of the form 'it's, which I take to be not a possessive, but the plural of *it*,  with quotation marks around the singular 'it'. It is the first time I have seen part of a word in inverted commas. Clearly this is something you have not done without consideration. My own inclination would have been to have written 'its'.

Comment: This is how I would write it: "Yeah, the more I see of it, the more it seems over-hyped". (Note the repetition of "the more...", which reinforces the sense you are emphasising.)

Comment: @WS2 It wasn't my first choice, but italicising only part of a word is not possible in comments. Setting it all on quotes grates on my OCD as being logically silly, so the weird interpunctuated version won out…

Answer (score 4):

That sentence would make more sense as

> The more I see of it ***the more*** it seems overhyped.

The original sentence lacks the effect of the increased exposure.

Comment: This is an appropriate answer, but does not thoroughly explain why the sentence is ungrammatical.  The problem with the original is that it omits half of a two-part conjunction: *the + comparative X, the + comparative Y.*  Examples: *the more, the merrier; the more I see of him, the less I like him; the larger the Roman empire grew, the harder it was to prevent its dissolution.*

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> "*The more I see of it the more overhyped it looks/seems*"

Consider these other sourced examples:

> *The more I see of it [the more unhappy I become](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD230.PDF)* - cs.texas.edu
>
> *The more I see of it, [the more rotten it becomes](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=pJQi51Z2E5QC&pg=PT104&lpg=PT104&dq=%22the+more+i+see+of+it+the+more%22&source=bl&ots=A-A_w4Ck_T&sig=KGcQSXhMuWeawvf1Sj8eVvojpBY&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=mS19U6ycGcOM7QbGm4DACQ&ved=0CFUQ6AEwCQ)* - Howard Sounes - 2011 - True Crime

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that having two its in a sentence can be a problem, that is not always the case.  It's only a problem when each it has a different meaning.  For example:  When a starfish loses an arm, it grows it back.  The first it must mean the starfish, and the second it must mean the arm.

Although there were grammatical errors in the sentence you provided, the double it isn't one of them.